# Can't access Go libraries

Tags: git, go

I had a working go project and I added some libraries to it.
All was working fine till this step. Then I pushed my code to server. Again I tried to take fresh clone the repository and I am getting following error.

***go file not find error***

When I try to do ***go get*** - (repo again) I get

```
go get -u github.com/jinzhu/gorm
package github.com/jinzhu/gorm: directory "/testapp/src/github.com/jinzhu/gorm" is not using a known version control system
```

What is wrong in this approach??

And When I am checking repository I can see git library repository point to some other repository commit.
[image]

Comment: what's yout $GOPATH ?

Comment: export GOPATH=/testapp

Comment: when i try to delete package manullay and do go get all is working but not with fresh cloned project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this approach and it worked as this was the only work around i was left with:

Fresh clone the project and navigate inside it;
Created `install.sh` which would set GOPATH, remove libraries and then re download it.

```
#!/bin/sh

#GET current working directory
CURRENT_DIR=`pwd`
echo "GOPATH is pointing to ${CURRENT_DIR}"
#Export GOPATH for current working directory
export GOPATH=${CURRENT_DIR}

#Change Directory permission to executable
chmod +x ${GOPATH}

#Delete github dependency so that they can be reinstalled
#Github Issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18591

#Modify this script if you are adding any other packages
rm -rf ${GOPATH}/src/github.com

#dependencies.txt contain list of go get -u (repo path)
#dependencies in new line add any new dependency and execute install.sh again
sh dependencies.txt
```

File dependencies.txt

```
go get -u -v github.com/gorilla/mux
go get -u -v github.com/gorilla/handlers
go get -u -v github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
```

Then finally run script which would boot my application
`run.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

#GET current working directory
CURRENT_DIR=`pwd`
echo "GOPATH is pointing to ${CURRENT_DIR}"

#Export GOPATH for current working directory
export GOPATH=${CURRENT_DIR}

echo "Starting server at http://localhost:9096"
#Run server instance
go run ${GOPATH}/path/to/main/file/Main.go
```

All this hold true with following directory structure:

`Project Root
-----bin
-----pkg
-----src
-----src/github.com/
-----src/github.com/gorilla/mux
-----src/github.com/gorilla/handlers
-----src/yours/project/code`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue just today and I fixed it by initializing a `.git` repo inside the local dependency. So inside `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` run:

```
git init 

git add . 
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, using go 1.12 on a MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things you can do.

1. Check your version of your GO if not the latest version then update your GO to version  `1.7`
2. Delete the repo and clone again after updating GO.
3. You could try to create new export for Golang directory with the following step :

> ```
> export GOPATH=/home/golang/    => try to modify your golang dir here
> ~$ mkdir -p $GOPATH
> ~$ go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm
> ```

this kind of problem mention in these link :

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6175
- https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/21342/

I think the latest version has fix this issue. Hope it

Comment: GO version output is 
go version go1.7.4 darwin/amd64

Comment: what os are you using, windows?

Comment: I'm using linux/amd64. if your issue still exist then you need to create issue in go repository

Comment: My Os is macSierra

Comment: i am not able to get what the solution can you please help me here.

Comment: @sector11 please try the step 3. maybe it could help you